# Need help in understanding a plan- Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table

```
index_test(id number,empid number,name varchar2(30));
```

I have made a composite index on columns empid  & name.
I was testing a concept that says when I use OR clause index is not used.
so I wrote this query

```
select * from index_test where empid='950604' or name='5OMVXGH6G5';
```

but I got a result which is unexpected to me. it does use the index but also scans the full table.  Please help me understand what's happening here.

Here is the plan -

```
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2255565997                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                         |    11 |   231 |  9695   (1)| 00:01:57 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   1 |  CONCATENATION               |                         |       |       |            |          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL          | INDEX_TEST              |     1 |    21 |  9682   (1)| 00:01:57 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| INDEX_TEST              |    10 |   210 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | SAMPLE_INDEX_INDEX_TEST |    10 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

   2 - filter("NAME"='5OMVXGH6G5')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
   4 - access("EMPID"=950604)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
       filter(LNNVL("NAME"='5OMVXGH6G5'))
```

Comment: "Coming straight to the point" is an oxymoron. Next time, just state your question instead of including greetings and such meaningless phrases :) We're here to help, anyway!

Comment: Also, don't just link to something that might not even work in our browsers. Just included a *detailed* explanation of what you're expecting to get and what you're actually getting in your question.

Comment: "I got a result which is unexpected", yes, but what **did** you expect?

Comment: @Asfakul Islam please run  a command: `explain plan for select * from ...... (rest your query)` and then `SELECT * FROM table( DBMS_XPLAN.Display)`, then copy a result of the last query (please copy it as a text !!!! - not html, not bitmap etc. Pleas also copy a whole explain plan, including "predicate information" printed at the bottom of the plan) and append it to the question. The plan you showed in this link (as html) is incomplete and unreadable. Thank you.

Comment: @kordirko Thanks Kordiko. I have included the plan.

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the plan, you will see this line: `|   1 |  CONCATENATION`
This is a sign that Oracle decided to use "OR expansion" optimalization method.

More on this you can find here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_transform.htm#GUID-0D5B9093-CDEA-45AC-A607-1F0D8F2615DD

In short: in this method Oracle transforms a query with OR condition:

```
select * from index_test 
where empid='950604' or name='5OMVXGH6G5'
```

into a form:

```
SELECT * FROM index_test 
   WHERE name='5OMVXGH6G5'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABLE
   WHERE empid='950604' and not( name='5OMVXGH6G5' )
```

Why Oracle did that ? Well - I really don't know.
It looks very strange to me.
Maybe your statistics are stale ?

Comment: Stats are not stale, before running the query I ran dbms_stats.gather_table_stats .

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an OR condition, the optimiser needs to fetch the result of both the queries: one matching the empid and the one matching the name.

Since you are selecting * - all columns, the optimiser has decided it is more efficient to do a full scan in addition to just using the index INDEX_TEST.

I can give a more helpful answer if you can mention what columns are in the indexes.

Comment: Thanks , name and empid columns has indexes on them with name being the leading column.

Comment: What are the columns in each index?

Comment: there is only one index. SAMPLE_INDEX_INDEX_TEST

Comment: INDEX_TEST is the table name.

Comment: To understand what is going on, you need to post what columns are covered in each index and what columns are there on the table (not indexed)

Comment: As I had said in my original post,  table INDEX_TEST has 3 columns ( id, name , empid)  - only one index SAMPLE_INDEX_INDEX_TEST that covers columns (name, empid) , let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Three things:
1. The optimiser may not start using an index till you have gathered stats on the table and index. Do try gathering stats on both and see if it picks up the index.

2. Try running with the hint 
    select * /*+ index(sample_index_index_test) */ from index_test where empid='950604' or name='5OMVXGH6G5';

3. The optimiser may have decided it is more effircient to just do a full table scan since you are selecting all columns and the index only covers partly - that is the explanation if (1) above does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, there is an `OR` clause in the query which means oracle has to look at both the conditions around the `OR` independently.

Looking at the explain plan, here is how it works -

Step 1. First it will look at all rows which satisfy the condition -

```
NAME='5OMVXGH6G5'
```

Step 2. Then it will look for rows that satisfy the condition -

```
EMPID=950604
```

(oh and make sure you don't use quotes when comparing a number column to a value)

Step 3. Once it gets these two results, it will join the two to get the final result

You have a composite index on `(EMPID, NAME)`. This will only help you in cases where you are searching for both `empid` and `name` together, but not when searching for just one of them separately. As expected, it used the index to get EMPID pretty quick (because that is the leading column in the index) but there was no way other than FULL TABLE SCAN to search the `NAME`.

If `EMPID` is the leading column in a composite index, you want to have `empid` in the search condition. The step1 of your search has just `NAME` in it and that is why it can't use the index.

What you should do -

1. If the composite index is not being used for other queries and you just created it for this query, then drop it.
2. Create 2 different indexes on the columns `empid` and `name`. This way both your step1 and step2 can use the indexes.